# Musing about variable declaration and the typedef specifier in c++

Tags: c++, typedef, declaration

If you want to declare an `int` you do for instance

```
int x;
```

You could after assign a value to `x` (or "define" `x`) for instance as follows :

```
x = 3;
```

Of course, you could have done directly

```
int x = 3;
```

There are types whose variables should be declared and defined at the same time, for instance

```
const double y = 2.3;
```

as well as type whose variables you simply can't declare and define at the same time, for instance a pointer to an array of three `char`'s :

```
typedef char (*pc3)[3];
char c3[3] = "ok";
pc3 apc3 = &c3;
```

(Am I wrong on the two previous examples ? Is there a one-liner (only one semi-column allowed) for the last one ?)

Consider now the following function pointer definition :

```
typedef int (*ipfunci)(int);
ipfunci fptr = &f; // where f is some int -> int function
```

(no one-liner for this as far as I know). Perfectly legal of course, but what about

```
typedef int (ifunci)(int);
```

Perfectly legal as well, but you can't define a variable of "type" 'ifunci' after having declared it, and what's it's use ?

This boils down to my real question : looking at

```
typedef char (*pc3)[3];
typedef int (*ipfunci)(int);
```

one sees an analogy between the two definitions, if one decides to see a size 3 array of `char`'s as a function

```
0 -> char
1 -> char
2 -> char
```

One could also see

```
typedef int * pi ;
```

as the definition of the "type" `pi` as constant function with value equal to an `int`.

How far does this synthactic and functional analogy go ? What is behind types whose definitions really require a `typedef` : are they systematically "functional" types ?

Comment: The similarity between use and declaration was intentional in early C. It's proved to be impractical because declarations become too complex for humans. Essentially the C declaration syntax doesn't support substitution. And so it's pointless to seek the limits of the system. In practice just avoid all more complicated C declaration, by judicious use of type definitions and C++ `auto`.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I thought that declaring a variable in `c++` was assigning it a "type" while defining it was given a value to it. But I am wrong, just had a look, for the second time in my life, to the standard (2003, 3.1). Anyway, my question remains valid with these definitions for "definition" and "declaration", isn't it ?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "The similarity between use and declaration was intentional in early C" --> would you have a reference perhaps ? Thx anyway !

Comment: “Generalization was required: given an object of any type, it should be possible to describe a new object that gathers several into an array, yields it from a function, or is a pointer to it. For each object of such a composed type, there was already a way to mention the underlying object: index the array, call the function, use the indirection operator on the pointer. Analogical reasoning led to a declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax in which the names typically appear.” – Dennis M. Ritchie, (https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

Comment: `char (*apc3)[3] = &c3;` and `int(*fptr)(int) = &f;` are valid syntax. The initialization of these pointer types are not special in any way other than being harder to read. The place where you put the type name is the same place where you should put the variable name when not using a `typedef`. Thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf for pointing to me that this doesn't actually answers the question.

Comment: @AndréSassi Was just reply to your "comment/answer" : what's really going on behind `char (*apc3)[3] = &c3;` and `typedef char (*pc3)[3];` then ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Those declarations are for a variable `apc3` as "pointer to `char[3]`" (with its initialization) and for a type alias `pc3` also as "pointer to `char[3]`". My comment is that pointer to array or pointer to function are not different from any other type regarding variable initialization, so there is no such types that you mention in the question: *What is behind types whose definitions really require a typedef : are they systematically "functional" types ?*

Comment: @AndréSassi You are perfectly right. I stupidly thought at some point that there were types not definable without ``typedef`s, which is obviously false, as I know now.